# How to handle deezer IDs vocabulary

Tags: deezer

each song can have different IDs in different countries (see [Deezer APsI: example of non-streamable song for country limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958029/deezer-apsi-example-of-non-streamable-song-for-country-limitation/) for detalis); having said that, which is the best practice to handle this in a deezer APIs based application?

Is there anything (like a "superID") which tells me that song A having ID 7 and song A having ID 8 are actually the same song?

As far as I have understood, the difference in catalog among countries shouldn't be huge so a song available in country X is usually available in all the other countries too in most of the cases...but considering the above difference in IDs vocabulary, is this still true? I.e. a song having ID 12345 in country X is available as 12345 in all the other countries in most of the cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Currently, the best practice is to use the readable flag on the JSON.

   - If you build your requests on client side (JS&co), the api geolocate the request with the client location.
   - If you build your requests on server side, the api use the geolocation of your server except if you use &access_token argument and the user is premium, the api use the geolocation of the subscription of the user.
2. No superID.
3. Yes, Most of the time, the identifiers are the same in all countries.

Comment: 1: so I'm forced to execute a http://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/ call for each song in my playlist to be sure: there isn't any way to detect it when the player attempts to play it, right? Maybe a group call will be available (ask info about several tracks using one call)?

2: OK, so here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958029/deezer-apsi-example-of-non-streamable-song-for-country-limitation you found that rihanna example just by artist+song-title match, right?

3: OK